# Cannot read property 'Query' of undefined

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables, google-visualization

In this code snippet
`

```
1) function gvizSelect(tableid) {
2)  var uri = "SELECT geometry FROM " + tableid + " WHERE name = 10095";
3)  var queryText = "http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=" + encodeURIComponent(uri);
4)  var query = new google.visualization.Query(queryText);
5)  query.send(getData);
6) }
```

`

I have confirmed that the queryText url will produce the proper response set when browsed directly; however line 4 is generating the following error; "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Query' of undefined."

Here is a complete html file that demonstrates the error I am receiving

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Indianatrails.com</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
  <script type=text/javascript>
    google.load('visualization', '1', 
            {
              'packages':['corechart', 'table', 'geomap']
            }
    );
    var tableid = '1ZxSfeVZWVm_PuTe8Q5THFwmyR0NcGQzbSdCvQds';
    var uri = "SELECT geometry FROM " + tableid + " WHERE name = 10095";
    var queryText = "http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=" + encodeURIComponent(uri);
    var query = new google.visualization.Query(queryText);
    query.send(getData);
  </script>
  <body>
  <h1>Test</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am at a loss (after several days reading documentation and examples) to figure out why this is not working.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: are you including the [visualization API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs)?

Comment: Yes.  That is included as a script block in the HTML file calling this.

Comment: but wasn't in your initial question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using google.load(), you need to wait until the script is loaded before using it.  You can set a call back function (google.setOnLoadCallback).

```
  <script type=text/javascript>
    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(runQuery);
    google.load('visualization', '1', 
            {
              'packages':['corechart', 'table', 'geomap']
            }
    );
function runQuery() {
    var tableid = '1ZxSfeVZWVm_PuTe8Q5THFwmyR0NcGQzbSdCvQds';
    var uri = "SELECT geometry FROM " + tableid + " WHERE name = 10095";
    var queryText = "http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=" + encodeURIComponent(uri);
    var query = new google.visualization.Query(queryText);
    query.send(getData);
}
  </script>
```

Of course then I get an error that getData is not defined (because it isn't)